# How to use curl with S3 protocol to upload object swift openstack?

Tags: amazon-s3

I want to upload file to Swift Openstack using s3 protocol with curl

```
#!/bin/bash
file=README.md
bucket=bucket
resource="/${bucket}/${file}"
contentType="application/x-compressed-tar"
dateValue=`date -R`
stringToSign="PUT\n\n${contentType}\n${dateValue}\n${resource}"
s3Key=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
s3Secret=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
signature=`echo -en ${stringToSign} | openssl sha1 -hmac ${s3Secret} -binary | base64`
curl -X PUT -T "${file}" \
  -H "Host: https://xxxxx.com" \
  -H "Date: ${dateValue}" \
  -H "Content-Type: ${contentType}" \
  -H "Authorization: AWS ${s3Key}:${signature}" \
  https://xxxxx.com/${bucket}/${file}
```

What's wrong with my script?
It's always response 404 error

Answer (score 0):

I think it's failing because the URI you are trying to hit is a protected URL and you need to pass auth token as well before making this request.

Comment: In this script I use access key and private key, I think nothing relate to auth token